# How can I delete non-english words from text file?

Tags: text-processing, language

I want to delete all words, which are not English, from the text file.

I have done some research about the topic on google and have found a python tool which is named pyenchant for this task. I have tested some English words on pyenchant but unfortunately, it does not function it supposed to do. It cannot recognize some English words such as "codependence".

```
>>> import enchant
>>> d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
>>> d.check("codependence")
False
```

I am wondering that is there any tool to delete non-english words from a text file. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer; it's just that it's too big to be a comment.

[pyenchant](https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant):

> Python bindings for the Enchant spellchecker. ... Enchant is used to check the spelling of words and suggest corrections for words that are miss-spelled. **It can use many popular spellchecking packages** to perform this task, including ispell, aspell and MySpell.

First step - did you try other spell checkers, or other English dictionaries for the same spell checker?

---

Second: Googling for  `pyenchant alternative` gives [this Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/89zgcc/pyenchant_maintaining_discontinued/), which says

> Here's another option that looks superior, however: https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell

Although I am unsure , as Pyenchant is simply a wrapper around Enchant, which is still being maintained, and Pyecnahnt as it stands does not seem to be the problem - the dictionary does. It would still be worthwhile to give this a try, though.

---

See also [pyenchant is unmaintained: path forward?](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/spelling/issues/13) which recommends [PyHunShell](https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell)